# Firebase Dashboard rounding Integer to even number

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Adding a big number in Firebase Dashboard is always rounding it to an even number.

For example adding this 10156050407559741, it changes to 10156050407559740 or 10154224540777163 to 10154224540777164.

Comment: This has been answered on this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31946165).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing from @MichaelLehenbauer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946165/4625829):

> Integers between 2^52 and 2^64 may lose precision (get rounded to the nearest integer representable by a 64-bit float).

And from the options on the same post, it would be best to store the numbers as Strings instead (still depending on your use-case though):

> **Store the numbers as strings**. As you suggested, you can just store the number as a string. But this can be inconvenient and does limit the validation you can do in the security rules.